# cubejs command not found | After Install I am unable to run command

Tags: javascript, frameworks, analytical, cube.js

[image]

I install cube.js using this command `yarn global add cubejs-cli` 
after executing its shown as done. when I enter the command `cubejs` terminal said `cubejs` command not found. I don't know how to move forward. Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It usually means npm or yarn are installed for root user rather than for regular one. You can try `sudo npm install -g cubejs-cli` to install Cube.js CLI for root user.